# using geopy for finding a great circle distance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopy, great-circle

I have a dataframe with columns "start lat", "start lon", "end lat" and "end lon". I want to use geopy to calculate distance for each row using above four columns. Plz help.

```
from geopy.distance import great_circle
great_circle([df['start station latitude'],
              df['start station longitude']],
             [df['end station latitude'],
              df['end station longitude']])
```

Comment: figured it out...  `df.apply(lambda x: great_circle((x['start station latitude'],x['start station longitude']), (x['end station latitude'],   x['end station longitude'])).miles, axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Just converting your comment into an answer because I was trying to find the same thing and nearly missed it ...

```
df.apply(
    lambda x: great_circle(
        (x['start station latitude'], x['start station longitude']),
        (x['end station latitude'], x['end station longitude'])
    ).miles,
    axis=1)
```